# При подключении телефона к компу по usb на рабочем столе Samsung Dex плитка а не иконки

Tags: android, samsung

Всем привет ! Вопрос специфический.

На компе установлен Samsung Dex. Все работало отлично, но видимо обновления пришли на телефон. Теперь при подключении к компу телефона через usb кабель, - (на компе) на рабочем столе (в окне) Dex иконки приложений выглядят как плитка ?!

И иконки не помещаются в размер плитки, (размер прямоугольника плитки полностью заполнен изображением иконки приложения причем криво) Если зайти в список установленных приложений (свайп вверх) то там вообще дичь !

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это исправить ?!

Comment: ¿Где версии приложений и системы, хотя бы скриншоты какие-нибудь? ¿И отчего бы не написать сразу в поддержку samsung?

Answer (score 0):

Перезагрузил телефон, - проблема исчезла ...